# Custom shape for Listview item in flutter

Tags: flutter, listview, shapes

I want to create a horizontal Listview for custom shape. I had tried with custom paint then this shape is created but it not set side by side in listview in a flutter. If anyone know how to create then please share it. Thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: `child: ListView.builder(
scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
itemCount: 100,
itemBuilder: (ctx, i) {
return Align(
child: Container(
width: 200,
height: 100,
decoration: BoxDecoration(
border: Border.all(color: Colors.black, width: 2),
borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32),
color: Colors.green.withOpacity(0.75)),
),
widthFactor: 0.8,
);
},
),` - of course you have to replace `Container` with your shape

Comment: and the shape should be done with a custom `ShapeBorder`, not `CustomPainter`

Comment: @pskink Thank you for your reply. As you said in comment to replacing container with created shape. But is not give an exact view as shown in the image.  Here two parallelogram is side by side which is not achieved with your solution. Or custom shape I will change CustomPainter to ShapeBorder.